# Can you have wildcard characters in a cell in an IF statement?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to set up a table that will allow for very quick classification of sites across about 50 different characteristics. The method I have thought of but am unsure if it's possible is as follows.

- `Worksheet A`: the raw data about 100R x 50C with each cell
  describing a characteristic of that row where the last column is the
  overall classification.
- `Worksheet B`: a table of about 5R x 50C with the columns
  corresponding to the columns in `Worksheet A`.

A row of `Worksheet B` would look something like:

```
* | * | * | 1 | * | 3 | * | Y | * | ... | * | * | * |
```

And a row from `Worksheet A` that corresponds with this data would look something like:

```
A | B | C | 1 | 5 | 3 | Z | Y | 1 | ... | F | 2 | X | High Priority
```

Where the asterisks indicate a wildcard where I don't care what the content is. All of the other cells would be required conditions. Then I was thinking of applying an array formula on the last column to get the classification. Something like:

```
{=IF(AND(A2:BV2='Worksheet B'!$A$2:$BV$2), "High Priority", "Low Priority")}
```

But Excel takes the asterisks as literal string content and evaluates it as `FALSE`.

Is there a way to make this work? Or an alternative method that would be just as simple to implement?

Comment: For starters, you could use `OR` instead of `AND`. For example: `=IF(OR(A1=1,B1=1,C1=1),"One of the 3 cells equals 1","No match")`

Comment: I require all characteristics to match to provide a valid classification. I have updated the question to reflect that I require all of the specified characteristics to match.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you're trying to do with wildcards, I thought you're trying to match certain columns to specific values while allowing any value in other columns.  Perhaps it would help if you [edit] your question to provide an examples of your data, as well as your expected output.

Comment: I've updated the question, I hope that's a little clearer now.

Comment: COUNTIF and SUMIF allow you to use wildcards e.g. =COUNTIF(C6:C17,"J*") where C6:C17 contain months of the year, will return how many months start with "J" i.e 3. Maybe that might help.

Comment: @JohnF The evaluation criteria is within the cells in `Worksheet B`. So I can't just type "J*" (or similar) into the formula bar. It needs to reference a cell. The problem is that Excel treats the contents of cells as string literals and won't pickup the wildcard character.

Comment: @MowgliB OK in my example if I had "J" in cell C1 for example I could do  =COUNTIF(C6:C17,C1&"\*") i.e. build the search string with concatenation. Also, if you want to search for the actual * character, you use the escape character ~, so to count cells with a * in them, you do =COUNTIF(<range>,"~*"). Hope this helps with similar problems.

Comment: @JohnF That still wouldn't work because in this scenario the wildcard character needs to be inside the referenced cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to the bottom of it with a reasonably elegant solution. Please post criticisms if there is a situation where this won't work.

```
={IF(SUM(IF(A2:BV2='Worksheet B'!A2:BV2,0,1))=COUNTIF('Worksheet B'!A2:BW2,"x"),"Top Priority", "Low Priority")}
```

Where `x` is for those cells in which I don't care about the outcome. So instead of "*", I am using "x" in the cells above such that `Worksheet B` is more like:

```
x | x | x | 1 | x | 3 | x | Y | x | ... | x | x | x |
```

If anyone is interested, the formula works by counting all of the mismatched elements and checking them against the number of cells with "x" in the result. If these two numbers are equal, the number of mismatches is equal to the number of cells we don't care about.